# Generate Price-Ranges in Java from Big-Integer-List

Tags: java, dynamic, range, webshop, price

I hava a list of Products, which have a Price as a BigInteger. I want to create dynamic price-ranges to filter the product-search, like google does on google.com/shopping:

[image: dynamic price ranges from google shopping]

How do i calculate good dynamic price ranges from the given list of items/prices? I tried google but couldn't find any good results or any solution at all! I do **NOT** want to define Ranges by hand and simply add the prices to the given ranges....

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter your products, e.g. with the Java 8 Streaming API (if Java 8 is available):

```
List<Product> results = new ArrayList();    
products.stream().filter(p -> p.getPrice() > minPrice && p.getPrice() < maxPrice).forEach(results::add);
```

Of course, at the end of the Stream, you could do `.forEach(this::output);` instead.

If you need Support for older Versions, the equivalent would be a `for` loop:

```
for(Product p : products){
   if(p.getPrice() > minPrice && p.getPrice() < maxPrice)
      this.output(p); //or add to a list
}
```

You can of course wrap it up as a method:

```
public static List<Product> filterProducts(BigInteger minPrice, BigInteger maxPrice){
   List<Product> results = new ArrayList();    
   products.stream().filter(p -> p.getPrice() > minPrice && p.getPrice() < maxPrice).forEach(results::add);
   return results;
}
```

**Find ranges**

If you have 30 items you want to divide into 3 ranges, you want your ranges to be price of the lowest - somewhere between price of the tenth lowest and price of the eleventh lowest.

let's assume you already sorted your list somehow:

```
double[] calcRanges(List<Product> sortedProducts, int count){
    double result = new double[count + 1];
    result[0] = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
        int pos = (sortedProducts.getSize() * i) / count;
        result[i] = sortedProducts.get(pos).getPrice();
    }
}
```

The Problem is, you will get ranges like 2.99 - 3.49 / 3.49 - 12.35 etc.

That means that you will need to "round" prices. You can either make a static list of allowed range starts / ends and seek the next biggest range end:

```
double[] allowedRangeEnds = {0,1,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,10000};

//returns the smalles allowed rangeend which is > value
double getNextRangeEnd(double value){
    int i = 0;
    while(allowedRangeEnds[i] < value && i < allowedRangeEnds.length - 1){
        i++;
    }
    return allowedRangeEnds[i];
}
```

You could of course generate your ranges, in case your prices skyrocket and you don't want to change your static ranges:

```
List<Double> calcRangeEnds(double maxValue) {
    List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double base = 1;
    while(base / 2 <= maxValue) { //the last value added is base / 2
        result.add(base);
        result.add(base * 2);
        result.add(base * 5);
        base *= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Seems like the way i did NOT want to go. your minPrice and maxPrice values would be constants. i want to create the ranges dynamically

Comment: they do not have to be constants, you can make a function, see the edited answer.

Comment: They have to be final (or "effectively final"), but you can also do that with local variables just by specifying the `final` keyword (e.g.: `final int minPrice`).
Variables are effectively final if you only assign them once.
If you need to do a for loop and need to use the counting variable inside a lambda expression, just create a final variable inside the for loop and assign its value to the current value of the counting variable. This way, the variable is recreated in each loop and final.

Comment: The question is, how do i get good dynamic values for minPrice and maxPrice from the found prices.... if 10 prices are between 0 and 5, 20 between 5 and 20 and 5 between 20 and 100, the ranges should be {0,5}, {5,20}, {20,100}

Comment: Now i understand your question. You need to assign ranges according to the total number of items.
i'll edit the answer again, then

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks like the way to go!